# Using random variables inside a function in r

Tags: r

I'm running a simulation in r and this is the main function I'm using:

```
runBothArms<-function(HFincidence,r,cost,util,mod,matProb,baseCaseMat,HazardR,
       allCauseMortality,iniAge,noInfluenceYear,noRecurencYear,HFduration,s2){
          res<-foreach(n=1:100000,.combine = rbind) %dopar% 
                 mainSim(HFincidence,r,cost,util,mod,matProb,baseCaseMat,HazardR,
      allCauseMortality,iniAge,noInfluenceYear,noRecurencYear,HFduration,s2)
          return(calcRes(res,cost,mod))
          }
```

now it's time for me to perform a sensitivity analysis. lets say I want r to be varied between 0-5%, how can I do it with the function I currently have? because if I send to the function `r<-sample(0:5,1)` it just samples one number and runs the entire simulation with it.

Comment: try `r = 1:5` and then `sapply(r, runBothArms, ...)` where `...` should be replaced with the 13 other arguments of your function

Answer (score 0):

As @Ken S. suggests, you need to loop your function to run multiple simulations. Consider `lapply` to return a list of your function's return object whose length is equal to the input vector, here being `sample(0:5, 5)`

Below, *calcResults* will be a list of 5 for each iterated simulation where *r* now changes in loop being the loop variable. Be sure to replace *param* values with actual values:

```
calcResults <- lapply(sample(0:5, 5), function(r)
   runBothArms(hparam, r, cparam, uparam, mparam, mPparam, bCparam, HRparam,
               aparam, iparam, nIparam, nRparam, HFparam, s2param))
```